# Conditionally constrain a table field from being referenced to another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, unique

I have a table bar

```
CREATE TABLE bar(
  bar_id serial,
  good_bar boolean,
  PRIMARY KEY (bar_id) );
```

and a table foo

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  foo_id serial,
  side_a INTEGER REFERENCES bar(bar_id),
  side_b INTEGER REFERENCES bar(bar_id) 
  PRIMARY KEY (foo_id);
```

However once a "bar" entry is used in foo.side_a I want to prevent it from being used in foo.side_b and vice versa.

PostgreSQL CHECK constraints seem to be limited to the column on which the constraint is placed, and a composite primary key (side_a, side_b) doesn't provide coverage for something like

```
INSERT INTO foo(side_a,side_b) VALUES
(0, 1),
(1, 0);
```

which I want to raise some sort of error.

I know I should be able to use a function + trigger to do a check on inserts or updates but was wondering if there is not a simpler solution or if I'm going about the problem incorrectly.

EDIT for clarification:
The issue with having a single column for the bar_id references is that data in the  bar table will be transformed(external to the database) based on which side bar_id is assigned to.

The best analogy I can think of is that of chess pieces. Both sides will have the same pieces but the positions of those pieces can be thought of both from white's (side_a) perspective and black's (side_b) perspective.

There are further implementation details that rely on the existence of two distinct perspectives for the data.

Comment: Welcome. There is, of course, an obvious question... why have two fields in foo that each reference bar(bar_id). If there were only one field, then you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: Hey @Tedinoz thanks for the quick response. After foo is populated there will be some logic (outside of the database) that will transform elements of bar based on which side that element has been assigned to. I'll edit to the question to include this bit of information.

Comment: Interesting point. Then perhaps the solution is avoid two Integer fields, but rather have one Integer fields and one "other" field that identifies the "side". Otherwise it seems like you are creating a lot amount of trouble to resolve a _seemingly_ "simple" problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a unique index on expression:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON foo (greatest(side_a, side_b), least(side_a, side_b));

INSERT INTO foo(side_a,side_b) 
VALUES
    (1, 2),
    (2, 1);

ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "foo_greatest_least_idx"
DETAIL:  Key ((GREATEST(side_a, side_b)), (LEAST(side_a, side_b)))=(2, 1) already exists.
```